# Cassandra Data Imbalanced

Tags: cassandra

sort of new to cassandra and have somewhat of a noob question. I'm trying to gain some understanding as to:

1. What causes such a large imbalance in data size on disk, across cluster members.
2. How can i correct such imbalances.
3. If regularly checking #2, are there any other preventative tasks that can be taken to ensure it stays in balance.

   `Cassandra Version: 2.1.5
   Members: 15nodes
   Replication Factor: 3 on all column families
   Incremental Repair: Mon, Wed, Friday
   Full Repair: 28th of each month`

Current Issue: 3 of 15 nodes have approx 200GB more data than the rest of the cluster. Viewing from datastax UI it shows the data on disk at 500+GB on 3 memebers of the cluster, while the others are roughly at 350~GB

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you give `nodetool cfstats` output for your tables? Larger partitions can commonly cause hotspots

Comment: No problem, i can run a `nodetool cfstats | grep partition` to keep it short. Where should i post? It's quite a bit of information...

Comment: Just edit question and include the results from largest tables that seem most imbalanced. Also, do you use vnodes? how many tokens?